# How to open drawer navigator on onPress event

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigator, drawer, onpress

errors, I tried these 2 methods   help me! how to resolve this issue, openDrawer() is not working poperly

Comment: Please add more code instead of adding attachments. Add the file where you use this component in a navigator.

Comment: well this is not the proper answer but this happed to me once and I have tried everything for at least an hours after that I uninstalled the app and closed packager and build the app again and it was working fine. without changing any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.